# how to set the fileds for Facebook Realtime Update API to get friends online_presence

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

How we can get the online_presence of our friends using the facebook real time update API. Where we can set the filed properties for the facebook real time update api. The realtime update api settings is moved to payments section in the facebook app development and there is no option to add the fields in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

subscribe the fields through graph-api subscription post.

set the parameter &object="user"&fields="online_presence,gender,location"